# How do I load a GLTF model via intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I'm trying to get a validated GLTF file to load from a web page on Android phones using an intent. I've followed the instructions on the [ARCore developer site](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/scene-viewer), but I cannot get my model to load, I just get this message:

> "Cannot load object. Looks like there's something wrong with this
>   object"

But the model generates no errors in [Google's online previewer](https://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer-preview), and I can get the model to load up in GLTF model viewers.

Am I missing something? Is there an issue with the model that I'm not seeing? My test webpage is [here](https://espiox.com), the model itself is [here](https://espiox.com/models/stkl900a.gltf), and this is the html I'm using for the intent:

```
<a href="intent://espiox.com/models/stkl900a.gltf#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;S.browser_fallback_url=https://developers.google.com/ar;end;"></a>
```

Comment: If it helps, here is a log with an error message, seems like smth is wrong with the model: https://gist.github.com/Kristina-Simakova/44115e42fabcb06a5f254753fedf1a92

Comment: @mulan Thank you for that. We've been investigating possible causes with our models but we're having trouble narrowing it down. We think it may be an issue with how Cinema4D is exporting the GLTF files, but we can't work out what.